# Solving $\int_9^x\frac{16\;dt}{\sqrt t\;(16-t^2)}=\frac{2\pi}{3}+\ln\frac{2 +\sqrt x}{5\sqrt x -10}-2\tan^{-1}\frac{3}{2}-\ln5$ without integrating?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Is there a way to solve this equation without evaluating the integral?

> Solve for $x>9$:
> $$\int_9^x\frac{16\;dt}{\sqrt t\;(16-t^2)}=\frac{2\pi}{3}+\ln\frac{2 +\sqrt x}{5\sqrt x -10}-2\tan^{-1}\frac{3}{2}-\ln5$$
>
> Note: The answer must be $x=12$.

This question is related with Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. I tried differentiating both sides, but I eliminate the constant terms. Is there a way to do it without evaluating that integral?

Thank you.

Comment: I think finding the solution by solving the integral is straightforward and easy to follow.

Comment: Would one method be via a substitution of eg $t = tan^{-1}(\frac{s}{2})$?